# How do I get more difficulties on Destiny?

Tags: destiny

On Destiny I was wondering how you could get more difficulties for a story mission?

Comment: Its pretty obvious stuff, the difficulty options. If there are options, they present themselves on the screen before you jump into the mission. If you have not unlocked the difficulty, it will literally tell you on rollover what you ha e to improve. In fact, it does not even require rollover. **The difficulty itself is labelled with the level you require to play it**

Answer (score 1):

If it does not display it, there is none. Bungie removed almost all of the difficulty choices. I'd take a guess, whatever mission you're trying to do that with, there is none.

Answer (score 1):

Missions will have either the standard or harder mode of the stage which also uses the heroic modifier.

Next to the mission will be the recommended light level and a rating of what level of difficulty it is likely to present going through: Easy, Normal, Hard, Very Hard and Impossible.

When the rating shows impossible you will not be able to select the higher difficulty until you increase your light by improving your equipment.